# how to set SwitchDrawerItem checkbox of mikepenz android library from other method

Tags: android, drawer, materialdrawer

I am using the lib MaterialDrawer (https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer).
i can set SwitchDrawerItem true of false on drawerbuilder with the command below:

```
new SwitchDrawerItem().withName("Record audio").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_microphone).withChecked(true).withIdentifier(111).withOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener).withSelectable(false),
```

but now i have other method (using floating button) that will set this SwitchDrawerItem to true.
 i had tried

```
result.setSelection(111, true);
```

it only sets selection but not check the checkbox.

please help me 
.
Many thanks.

Best regards, ben

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update an `Item` after the drawer was built there are multiple options. Either way you keep the reference to this item

```
SwitchDrawerItem myItem = new SwitchDrawerItem(). ...;
```

Or you get the `Item` from the `Drawer` again:

```
SwitchDrawerItem myItem = (SwitchDrawerItem) drawer.getDrawerItem(111);
```

After you have the reference to the item you can change it:

```
myItem.withChecked(false);
```

And then notify the `MaterialDrawer` about the update:

```
drawer.updateItem(myItem);
```

After this your `Drawer` will show the changed state.

You can also see all methods of the `Drawer` in it's [JavaDoc](http://static.javadoc.io/com.mikepenz/materialdrawer/5.3.6/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/Drawer.html)